The problem of being unable to navigate functions encountered while using VS Code
While using VS Code, I encountered an issue where I couldn't navigate functions within the WSL: Ubuntu environment.
After several investigations, I found that using the latest version 1.20.5 of the C/C++ plugin caused this problem.However, reverting back to version 1.15.4 resolved it.  What could be the possible reasons for this?
